# Add text to chapter titles directly after chapter number

Tags: memoir

I'm writing a document using the Memoir document class with the `article` option enabled using `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,article,oneside]{memoir}`. How do I add the text "chap." after the chapter numbers, but before the skip between chapter numbering and its title? Preferably the chapters' entries in the ToC should also be affected.

The `\afterchapternum` and `\midchapskip` macros is described in Memoir's documentation, but I couldn't get it to work. My attempt to redefining `\afterchapternum` (which didn't work out):

```latex
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}[0]{chap. \midchapskip}
```

### Example:

The LaTeX document

```latex
\documentclass[article]{memoir}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Lorem Ipsum}
\end{document}
```

currently results in the chapter title

```
1  Lorem Ipsum
```

but I want the result to be

```
1 chap.  Lorem Ipsum
```

Comment: As always on this site please post a full self contained minimal example. That makes it a lot easier to help (when you don't have to guess 90% of a sample document). It should not be that hard, but the article setup is probably special and I'd guess it does not use afterchapternum at all (feel free to have a look in `memoir.cls`), I'll have a look tomorrow (not at pc at the moment)

Comment: @daleif: I've added a self contained minimal example now to my top post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment. The article option causes chapters to be typeset using the article chapter style. Here is the code

```
\makechapterstyle{article}{%
\chapterstyle{default}
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{3.5ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstart}{\vspace{\beforechapskip}}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{2.3ex \@plus .2ex}
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\chapnumfont}{\chaptitlefont}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter\quad}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}}
```

Thus you could just copy and change `\printchapternum`

Comment: Thanks! To make it clear to people reading this: the solution is to add `\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{\chapnumfont \thechapter \enskip chap. \quad}`. The `\enskip` command add a small space between the chapter number and the text `chap.`

You don't happen to know what I should do to make my change also affect the ToC?

Comment: Lookup `\cftchaptername` in the manual